# Simple Python Question about index of string

Tags: python

I have the string:

```
119.95119.95
```

This string is not always the same and will change depending on the input. However, it will always have two fullstops and we will always only want 2.dp

The output i am trying to achieve is:

```
119.95,119.95
```

Im sure it something simple. I tried using:

```
'{:,.2f}'.format(int(price))
```

however, the iterations of my attempts have all returned errors.

Comment: `i = s.find(".") + 3; print(f"{s[:i]},{s[i:]}")`?

Comment: b e a u t i f u l!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert the above string into formatted integer directly.

See there are 2 decimals in that string which cannot be present in any number and so it must give you error.

Now to get expected result out of input string, here is the approach:

1. Find the index of first `.`
2. get first number which would be till found index+2
3. second number would be the remaining string.

@MateenUlhaq has also done the same thing in above comment.

Here is the code which is self explanatory and you can use:

```
myString = "119.95119.95"
firstDotIndex = myString.find(".")

number1 = myString[: firstDotIndex+3]
number2 = myString[firstDotIndex+3 : ]

print("{0}, {1}".format(number1, number2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "119.95119.95"
```

Get the index of the first `.` and add 3 to get to the first character in the second number:

```
i = s.find(".") + 3
```

Use the index to slice the string:

```
first = float(s[:i])
second = float(s[i:])
```

Using `float()` assures that the slices are actually floating point numbers. A `ValueError` exception will be thrown if the conversion fails.

Print the slices and add a `,` between them:

```
print(f"{first:.2f},{second:.2f}")
```